# Comparing Reduce with other high-level functions in R

Tags: r, reduce

Let's say I have the following list:

```
mylist <- list(c("string", "_a"), c("string", "_b"), c("string", "_c"))
mylist
[1] "string" "_a"
[[2]]
[1] "string" "_b"
[[3]]
[1] "string" "_c"
```

I want to concatenate the strings within each element of my list, that is to say:

```
"string_a" "string_b" "string_c"
```

I have found out that the following command works:

```
sapply(mylist, function(x) Reduce("paste0", x))
```

I have also tried the following:

```
sapply(mylist, function(x) paste0(x))
```

but this does not work and returns the following:

```
     [,1]     [,2]     [,3]    
[1,] "string" "string" "string"
[2,] "_a"     "_b"     "_c"
```

Why does not this second method work? What reason is behind the different behavior of the two commands?

Comment: Your second method just runs per value and runs `paste0` on itself. As you would do `paste0(c("string", "_a"))`. If you want this to work, you could do `sapply(mylist, paste, collapse = "")`

Comment: Thank you David. Now I realize I did not correctly define my second command: you suggested the right form sapply(mylist, paste, collapse = ""). Actually, I typed sapply(mylist, function(x) paste0(x)) because the point of my question was the behavior of the Resume function. However, Investigating Reduce() more deeply, I see that it combines the first two elements of a vector with a function, then combines the result of that call with the third element, and so on (http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functionals.html). So, I understand that this is how Reduce() is acting in the case of mylist.